# converting a asp checkbox to iphone style on-off slider

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I had a checkbox in my asp.net page which I have to convert into iphonestyle on-off slider.
It uses javascript as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
      new iPhoneStyle('.on_off input[type=checkbox]');
      new iPhoneStyle('.css_sized_container input[type=checkbox]', { resizeContainer: false, resizeHandle: false });
      new iPhoneStyle('.long_tiny input[type=checkbox]', { checkedLabel: 'Very Long Text', uncheckedLabel: 'Tiny' });

      var onchange_checkbox = $$('.onchange input[type=checkbox]').first();
      new iPhoneStyle(onchange_checkbox);
      setInterval(function toggleCheckbox() {
        onchange_checkbox.writeAttribute('checked', !onchange_checkbox.checked);
        onchange_checkbox.change();
        $('status').update(onchange_checkbox.checked);
      }, 2500);
    });
  </script>
```

how can I get the text displayed on the button when it is toggled?
I can't find a way to check what is going on here in this script. And also,I want to know which event to fire.
Help!

Comment: checkout this link over here it could provide you with some infos http://labs.engageinteractive.co.uk/itoggle/

Comment: @Mingebag- thanx for the link, but I am still not able to arrive at any solution.

Comment: How is that possible there is everything that you need ..